# How to convert $('id1', 'id2') in Prototype JS to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I have `var something = $('id1', 'id2');`

What is the equivalent in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent is `var something = $('#id1, #id2');`. This will produce a jQuery object with both objects.

On the other hand, in jQuery the second argument of the constructor is for scope, so `$('#id1', '#id2')` would give you the element for `#id1` that was inside of the `#id2` element. It is equivalent to `$('#id2').find('#id1')` which is not the same as the combination you were looking for.

[jQuery uses css selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in order to target elements, and almost all of the native css selectors will work as an argument.

Comment: the prototypejs code I'm looking at did not have the hashes.  In prototype the id selector doesn't use hashes. So is it $('#id1, #id2') in jQuery?